# Windows Phone PhoneGap File Upload No Response

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-plugins

Using PhoneGap 3.4, Windows Phone 8. I am using the standard upload code, where  fullPath is the full path to a file captured previously by the camera, using `navigator.device.capture.captureImage`

Here is the code for the upload:

```
  var win = function (r) {
      alert("Code = " + r.responseCode);
      alert("Response = " + JSON.stringify(r.response));
      alert("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);

  };

  var fail = function (error) {
      alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
      alert("upload error source " + error.source);
      alert("upload error target " + error.target);

  };

  var options = new FileUploadOptions();


  options.fileKey = "media";
  options.fileName = "media";

  if (source == "mediaFile"){
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";

  }
  else{
    options.mimeType = "image/png";

  }

  var ft = new FileTransfer();

  ft.upload(fullPath, serverUrl, win, fail, options, true);
```

Nothing reaches the server. The same code works perfectly on iOS and Android.

Would appreciate insight.

Answer (score 0):

Please try out the following steps and share your results to get further help

- Ensure you have the right Permissions: WP8 needs the ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO capability to access photos in the media library. Capabilities are specified in the app manifest file, WMAppManifest.xml.
- Upload a static file from your solution or IsolatedStorage with hard coded url
- I can't predict how your fullPath looks like. Can you debug your code an share a sample url of a selected image?

Comment: The ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO permission exists. There is no problem in accessing the image taken by the camera or selected from the photo library. I am able to show it on the screen by setting the img src to the image url. The problem is only in the upload. The fullPath looks like: `\CapturedImageCache\WP_20140523_001.jpg`

Comment: To show the image on screen I use the image full path of the image is taken by the camera, or to the image uri if the image is selected from the gallery

Comment: Since I could not find a solution, I changed the code to capture an image or select image from photo library using `navigator.camera.getPicture` with `destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL`. So I would get a Base 64 encoding of the image as a string. Then I uploaded the string to the server with a jQuery post `jQuery.post`. In the server, I decoded the string into an image.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about version 3.4, but I was able to get version 3.5 working by removing line 733 from the `FileTransfer` plugin:

```
requestStream.Write(boundaryBytes, 0, boundaryBytes.Length);
```

This line was causing my WebAPI service to reject the POSTed file on WP devices only because the boundary was being added twice in a row to the body.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that an extra boundary is emitted into the request, which unfortunately causes my request fail in the form submission.

FileTransfer submission ends up look like this. (Note the extra boundary, included after the parameters, and before the file data itself.

```
------------------------------2f2329h7451fc52
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="CaseId"
7e282d21-2a4a-e411-9de6-000c29906b4b

------------------------------2f2329h7451fc52
------------------------------2f2329h7451fc52
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Files";
filename="///CapturedImagesCache/C__Data_Users_Public_Pictures_Camera Roll_WP_20141029_009_jpg.jpg" {data}
```

I've follow the the code, remove the one line to fix this issue.
For me, it is line # 758 of FileTransfer.cs

```
 requestStream.Write(boundaryBytes, 0, boundaryBytes.Length);
```

After commenting out this line my app now upload file successfully.

Reference URL: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6313